# How to login linkedIn using Jaunt or Jsoup or HtmlUnit in java?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, htmlunit, jaunt-api

I'm able to login via HTTP links. But LinkedIn uses HTTPS. This is the major problem to login to LinkedIn using Jaunt or Jsoup via HTTPS. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to simulate your broswer call for login by httpclient and then get the cookie saved in the variable for subsequent calls.